# SSO oidc keycloak handle redirect via backend apis

Tags: rest, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect, quarkus

We have implemented the following login API integrated with keycloak. Redirection is happening totally via backend and oidc properties in quarkus backend application properties. From Angular frontend it is calling this API and require to read logged in user details to show it on the screen.

Backend API -

```
@GET
public Response authUser(@QueryParam("redirect") String redirectUrl) {
  if (redirectUrl == null) {
    redirectUrl = frontendUrl;
  }
  return Response.status(302).location(URI.create(redirectUrl)).entity(new User(keycloakSecurityContext)).build();
}
```

Frontend -

```
ngOnInit() {
  const httpOptions = {
    params: new HttpParams().set('redirect', window.location.href)
  };
  return this.httpClient.get('/api/auth', httpOptions);

  if (error.status === 499) {
    const initialUrl = ${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host};
    window.location.assign(${environment.apiUrl}/api/auth?redirect=${initialUrl}${this.route.url});
  }
}
```

On successful login API is returning 302 status code with location and User details as response payload. Since 302 code is indicating browser for temporary redirect with location, angular application which is calling that API is not able to catch this response payload which contains username and its roles. Is there any workaround to solve this issue and capture the response payload ?

Note - We are using keycloak and login page resides in keycloak as keycloak theme.